# React: How mock functions and test component rendering with jest:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

Im very new to react/jest. Im trying to test a very simple react component that gets data from the server and renders the response. My component looks like the below:

```
export default class myComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

     async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            let response = await axios.get(`server/url/endpoint`);
            this._processSuccess(response.data);
        } catch(e) {
            this._processFail(e);
        }
    }

    _processSuccess(response) {
        this.setState({pageTitle: response.data.title, text: response.data.text});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="title">{this.state.pageTitle}</div>
        );
    }
}
```

Now I want to test this class. While I test:

1. I want to make sure componentDidMount() was not called
2. I want to pass test data to _processSuccess
3. Finally check the if the rendered output contains a div with class title that has the inner text same as what I supplied as response.data/pageTitle

I tried something like the below:

```
import React from 'react'
import MyComponent from './MyComponent'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme'

describe('MyComponent', () => {
    it('should display proper title', () => {
        const c = shallow(<MyComponent />);
        c._processSuccess(
            {data:{pageTitle:'siteName', test:'text'}}
        );
        // couldn't go further as Im getting error from the above line
    });
});
```

But, Im getting MyComponent._processSuccess is not a function error. What would be the proper way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shallow()` [returns an Enzyme wrapper](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html#-shallow-node-options-shallowwrapper) with some utils method to test the rendered component. It does **not** return the component instance. That's why you get the error when calling `c._processSucces()`. To access the component you can use the [`.instance()` method](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/instance.html) on the wrapper, so the following should work:

```
    const c = shallow(<MyComponent />);
    c.instance()._processSuccess(
        {data:{pageTitle:'siteName', test:'text'}}
    );
```

In order to avoid that component's `componentDidMount()` get called, you can try settings `disableLifecycleMethods` on the shallow renderer, but I'm not sure about that because here Enzyme's documentation is not 100% clear:

```
    const c = shallow(<MyComponent />, {
        disableLifecycleMethods: true
    });
```

Finally, you can check if the output contains the expected `<div>`, using Enzyme's `contains()` and one of [Jest assertion methods](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html):

```
    expect(c.contains(<div className="title" />)).toBe(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. yes I can call `_processSuccess` on the `instance()`. However, I also need to test the rendered output and see if my call to `_processSuccess` made any impact on it. if I try something like: `expect(c.contains(<div className="title" />)).to.equal(true);` afterwards will it work? in my case im getting something like, ` TypeError: Cannot read property 'equal' of undefined`

Comment: @KamrulKhan Your problem is that you are looking at Enzyme's examples: in the documentation they refer to the [chai assertion library](http://chaijs.com/), but since you are using Jest, I suggest you to use the [built-in one](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html). See my updated answer.